# Book exam online or in person UI design

Tags: user-expectation, users

I am trying to create a UI for booking an exam where the user need to select 'online' or 'in-person'. The stakeholders also want to highlight the online option so that users opt more for the online version.

My question is, when creating the UI what is better for the user, to have the option to select the date from the calendar first and then choose 'online' or 'in-person'

My mockup is now first select 'online' or 'in-person' and then the dropdown to select the location. Once location is selected the Date calendar shows up.

[image: my mockup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK as you have it now, but for reference, the reason why it's correct is because you must build an interface as a conversation between the user and the interface.

If you had the date first, users could face the issue of having to click through multiple options until they find the one that suits their preference, whether it's *online* or *in-person*.

By having the preference option set first, additional options that are subsets of that set will show up conditionally. This is easy to visualize with a user flow diagram. Using the calendar would require more `if` and `if not` conditionals, whereas the current method is straightforward:

```
If the user chooses the online option --> show the calendar with available dates.
If the user chooses the in-person option --> show the location(s) --> (selection action) --> show the calendar with available dates.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is correct as it is. The only possibility I would study to place the calendar in the first place is if it allows you to select at the same time the course type showing a double or a single option per day:

[image]